Can I make an array larger while keeping the original values unchanged?
--EDIT: Following Julien's comment I made a minimal reproducible example! It's at the end of the original post :) --
I have a code in Python that helps me find the intersection points between two curves; each time the f(frequency) equals one of the tangents (or cotangents). I save those values which correspond to the modes available for a given frequency. I iterate over a number of frequencies so I can know which modes propagate over which frequencies.
For each frequency (or pulsation) in my for loop, I find the intersection points with a program Intersection that returns the x and y positions in an array. I only need the x values so I keep them in an array called X_inter. I save each X_inter into a bigger array called arr_KX for easier manipulation later on.
Therefore the rows of arr_KX correspond to a given frequency and the columns correspond to a given mode (first column equals 0th mode and so on)
I can not know what the largest mode will be, therefore how many columns my array needs to have, until I have finished the if loop.
The problem is that for lower frequencies, I will have less modes than for higher frequencies. As you can see on the following code, when I try to resize the 'arr_KX' I will lose all previous information.
What should happen in the ideal case is that if a first frequency has 2 modes and a second frequency has 4, then arr_KX shows :
arr_KX = [[mode 1 of f1, mode 2 of f1, nan , nan ] , [ mode 1 of f2, mode 2 of f2, mode 3 of f2, mode 4 of f2]]
Or more readable:
arr_KX = [[m1,m2,nan,nan],[m1,m2,m3,m4]]
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Intersection as inter
np.seterr(all='ignore')
plt.clf()

height, width, lenght = 500e-6, 500e-6, 100e-6 
d = height/2
c0 = 3e8 
n_core = 5.2 
n_cladding = 1.
FntSze = 15 

"""
Solve this equations
"""
def cot(angle):
    return np.cos(angle)/np.sin(angle)

def TE_LHS_sym(var1):
    return np.tan(var1*d)

def TE_LHS_antisym(var2):
    return -cot(var2*d)

def TE_RHS(var3,pulsation_):
    return ((pulsation_**2*d**2*
             (n_core**2-n_cladding**2)/(c0**2*var3**2*d**2))-1)**(0.5)

start, end, Nx, NN = 100e9, 1000e9 + 1, 1001 ,21 
##Start and end of pulsation range, with NN the number of frequencies we work with and Nx the number of kx generated

f_range = np.linspace(start,end,NN)
w_range = f_range*2*np.pi 
k = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi,Nx)/d 

tol = 40. ##To limit the float points at discontinuity of tangents/cotangents

y_tan = TE_LHS_sym(k) ##Draw tan(kx*d)
y_tan[y_tan > tol] = np.nan ##Limits the aberrations at discontinuity
y_tan[y_tan < -tol] = np.nan

y_cot = TE_LHS_antisym(k) ##Draw cot(kx*d)
y_cot[y_cot > tol] = np.nan
y_cot[y_cot < -tol] = np.nan

init=0
size = 0

##PlOTTING
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(k*d,y_tan,label='tan($k_{x0}d$)' )
plt.plot(k*d,y_cot)#,label='-cot($k_{x0}d$)')

for init,omega in enumerate(w_range): #Loop for pulsations, starting at max and ending at min 
        y_RHS = TE_RHS(k,omega) #Draws RHS, intersaction points with tan/cot will give kx_mode
        y_RHS[y_RHS > tol] = np.nan
        plt.plot(k*d,y_RHS,marker='',label='RHS at $f$ = '+ str(round(omega*1e-9/(2*np.pi),2)) + ' GHz')
       
        ##Find intersection points between tan/cot, they will give kx_mode for a given w
        x_inter_tan,y_inter_tan = inter.intersection(k, y_tan, k, y_RHS)
        x_inter_cot,y_inter_cot = inter.intersection(k, y_cot, k, y_RHS) 
        plt.plot(x_inter_cot*d, y_inter_cot, '+k') ##Draws inter points cot//RHS
        plt.plot(x_inter_tan*d, y_inter_tan, '+k') ##Draws inter points tan//RHS
        
        plt.xlabel("$k_{x}d$ (in $rad.m^{-1}$)",fontsize=FntSze)
        plt.ylabel("",fontsize=FntSze)
        
        X_inter = np.sort(np.concatenate([x_inter_cot.copy(),x_inter_tan.copy()])*d) #Gives kx_m*d for a w
        KX_inter = X_inter/d
        if KX_inter.shape[0] > size :    #In order to know how many columns we need 
            size = KX_inter.shape[0]     
            arr_KX = np.zeros((NN,size)) #Create matrix NN*size == w_n*kx_modes
        bb = KX_inter.resize(size)       #Higher w_m have higher kx_modes, this sets them up in the same shape
        arr_KX[int(init),:] = KX_inter #Matrix w_n*kx_modes appends line at w_n of the kx_modes

When confronted with this problem I tried to solve it many times but never found a good solution. So I did a workaround and decided to generate my frequencies from the highest to the lowest in order to always start with the highest number of modes possible. This works most of the time (emphasis on most of the time) but I want to know how I could solve this array problem without inversing the generation of frequencies since it's going to give me some mayor problems as I continue working on the physics of this problem.
I can't quite remember what I did exactly since it's been weeks since I settled on my workaround, but I did try as many of the 'solutions' I could find on Google. Either with numpy or just the basic commands from python, the problem would still persist or a new one would arise.
With reshape (I think), the issue was that the mode values from a frequency would go to another frequency.
So I would have:
arr_KX =[[mode1 of f1,mode2 of f1,mode1 of f2,mode2 of 2],[mode3 of f2, mode 4 of f2, nan, nan]]
EDIT Here's the minimal reproducible example:
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

NN = [2,2,4,6,6]
size = 0
init = 0
for n in NN:
    KX_inter = default_rng().random((n)) #shape (n,)
    print(KX_inter)
    if KX_inter.shape[0] > size :
        size = KX_inter.shape[0]          #In order to know how many columns we need 
        arr_KX = np.zeros((len(NN),size)) #Create matrix Nx*size == w_n*kx_modes
    bb = KX_inter.resize(size)            #Higher w_m have higher kx_modes, this sets them up in the same shape
    arr_KX[int(init),:] = KX_inter
    
    init = init + 1
print(arr_KX)

You can also see that if you invert NN you won't get the problem, which has been my solution for the moment. But I wish I could do this code without this workaround.

So many words and I still don't understand the problem. Please cut the irrelevant stuff out and get to the point with a simplified [mre].

Without really understanding the issue, my guess is that if you don't know the size of an array, numpy aray is probably not the right structure and you may want to stick to native lists?

You really don't want to try extending existing numpy arrays, you can go over this SO question/answer that covers it greater detail. Dont use numpy arrays if you want to keep extending/resizing them

@Julien I added a minimal reproducible example, is it easier to understand that way?
Also, I can't use native list because I had the problem that I mention at the end of the original post.

Thanks for the comment @KaranShishoo but I have some trouble understanding the post you linked. If I understand correctly, for my case which is that I absolutely need to work with arrays, I would need to create a very large array and then cut it for it to work?

You could create the data structure using lists and afterwards convert it to a numpy array since at that point you would know the size.

Thanks @JohnColeman for your answer. Do you know how I could go on about doing so? I am not very profficient with Python and last time I tried using lists I had the problem that I describe at the end of my original post.

Where do you describe that? I don't see any mention of lists in the question. Make sure you avoid this problem

Thank you very much @Barmar ! I will update the original question tomorrow morning, I found the way to do what I was trying to do in th end. I did use lists to solve this problem jeje

After you update the question, post the solution in an Answer below, not in the question.

Done @Barmar , I hope I did it correctly. Thanks again for the help!

To solve this problem I had to make to loops. The original one where I find the Intersection points, but this time I add them into an empty list instead of an array. I also look for the longest size of my individual lists.
    X_inter = np.sort(np.concatenate([x_inter_cot.copy(),x_inter_tan.copy()])*d) 
    KX_inter_ = X_inter/d
    
    KX_inter = list(KX_inter_)
    KX_list.append(KX_inter)
    if len(KX_inter) > size:
        size = len(KX_inter)

Now that they are grouped together inside 'KX_list', I start another loop to add the necessary 'np.nan' into each individual list. Then I convert them into an np.array.
i = 0
for r in KX_list:
    s = len(r)
    arr0 = [ np.nan for _ in range (size-s)]
    KX_list[i].extend(arr0)
    i += 1
arr_KX = np.array(KX_list)

Here's a simple example to try in your consoles:
fruit = [[1,2],[2,3,3,4,2],[1,2,3]]
size = 0
for r in fruit :
    if size < len(r):
        size = len(r)
it = 0
for r in fruit :
    s = len(r)
    arr0 = [np.nan]*(size-s)
    print(arr0)
    fruit[it].extend(arr0)
    it = it+1
arr_fruit = np.array(fruit)
print(arr_fruit)

